# LXDE: Change text in logout session

Tags: linux, session, ubuntu, logout

I have installed LXDE on my Ubuntu PC (not Lubuntu). I want to change the text in the logout session. The default text is "Logout LXDE session ?". But I want to personalize it. I've already changed the picture of the logout session. Can you help me? Thank you very much.
BowStar

Comment: This is not a programming question. Try asking on https://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t know yet how to solve this in a completely and permanent way, but you can create a new logout dialogue box:

1. Make a Folder and, inside it, click with the right mouse button to create a new empty file (a simply txt file) with the name "temp-lubuntu-logout" (you can change the file name after the conclusion of the work.
2. Paste this text, changing the items to fit your options:

## !/bin/sh

lxsession-logout --prompt "Your custom message" --banner "Your logo" \
    --side "left | top | right | bottom (The position of the logo)"

3. Open with the terminal the folder where is your temp-lubuntu-logout file and make it executable with this command:

sudo chmod +x temp-lubuntu-logout

That’s all! You just created a script file!

4. To verify is it is working, write in the terminal:

./temp-lubuntu-logout

(dont forget the dot before the /)

Now I can’t help more them this. You need to link this script to the the command of a app. Or you can change the lubuntu-logout script with your new script file (you may, for example, rename the original script to "former-lubuntu-logout" and your file to "lubuntu-logout". Probably, the path to the "lubuntu-logout" file is /usr/bin).

https://crisnepita.wordpress.com/2012/08/12/cambiar-un-poco-la-ventana-de-cerrar-sesion-en-lubuntu/

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/170029/command-to-log-out-of-lxde-directly/171880

http://tunealxde.blogspot.pt/2015/02/tunea-el-dialogo-de-cierre-de-sesion-de.html

Answer (score 0):

### I have found a way to change it.

## Warning

This requires you to know what you are doing.

Use your favorite hex editor and edit file `/usr/bin/lxsession-logout`
Scroll all the way down the file, then go up until you see a human-readable section.
Over there, on a long string, there is the logout menu in bytes.

Once you change stuff in there, and save the binary, if you did not break something it will work. For deleting something, just overwrite its section with spaces, same for text and labels.
**Tip**: only edit and don't change any appearance order or add more bytes at some index because it will scramble the offset table of the file and will become corrupted.